# Babel failing on Export default from even when enabled

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

In my React app, I am getting the following error during compilation:

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'exportDefaultFrom' isn't currently enabled:
1 | export default from './CustomIcon'
  |
```

I have already installed a couple of babel packages, but it did not help. Here is a part of my `package.json`:

```
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.7",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
...
```

And this is the content of my `babel.config.json` file:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from"
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is my babel configuration ignored? Are there any other steps I need to do?

Comment: Seems you mixed the new things configuration/presets/plugins (v7) with the old ones cli/core (v6) which is likely the issue

Comment: So what parts of code should I modify and how?

Comment: Did you use `create-react-app` to generate the project?

Comment: Yes, I did use it.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using `create-react-app (CRA)`, you can't simply add the `babel.config.js` like that since it has been wrapped by `CRA`.

But we can achieve that by using package `react-app-rewired` which is able to modify configuration of `CRA`.

Here are a few steps you would follow up:

- Install deps:

```
yarn add -D react-app-rewired customize-cra
```

- Add the configuration file at root dir `config-overrides.js`:

```js
const { useBabelRc, override } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  useBabelRc(),
);
```

- Test your script by switching to `react-app-rewired` in your `package.json`:

```json
{
  "start": "react-app-rewired start", // Replace `react-scripts`
  "build": "react-app-rewired build",
  "test": "react-app-rewired test",
}
```

That's it!

Comment: Actually, you were right with your first comment about mixing babel v6 and v7. I just needed to convert all the v7 presets and plugins to v6 and it started to work. Thank you!